# Knots in regression and the dummy variable trap

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, nonlinear-regression, categorical-encoding, splines

I am running a knot-like type of regression and have a couple of questions:

Imagine that we are working with daily data that spans over $3$ years.

Consider the following model:

$y_t = \beta_{0, t} + x_{1, t}^{\beta_{1, t}}$

Where as $\beta_{1, t}$ is modelled as follows:

Imagine that we place three knots, one at the start of the dataset, one in the middle and one in the end and we use a weighting scheme for the days in between:

$\beta_{1, t} = \sum_j w_{j}(t) * b_{j, p}$

where as $b_{j, p}$ represents the knot and
$w_{j}(t) = \frac{k(t, t_j)}{\sum_{i=1}^J k(t, t_i)}$ where $k$ is just a linear kernel.

Lets say i now also wants to add knots based on the day of the week, these knots however will not be weighted with each other.

Lets say i group in weekends and weekdays:
$\alpha_j = \alpha_{weekend}$ if $dayoftheweek \in [saturday, sunday]$ else $\alpha_{weekday}$

Lets say now that i wanted to mix these two knot-types($\beta_{j, p}, \alpha_j$) together, how should i weight the "main-knots"($\beta_{j, p}$) and my day of the week knots in a manner that makes sense?

Secondly, am i running into the dummy variable trap here by having two dayofthweek knots, maybe just one would be sufficient?